# How can I get numerical answers to integrals involving the error function?

Tags: evaluation

This is the integral I am trying to evaluate in mathematica:

Integrate[Exp[-p^2/(m w h)], {p, -Infinity, Sqrt[h m w]}]

Can someone show me how to get a numerical answer out of this?

Comment: Can you read what you posted?

Comment: @belisarius I can if I copy and paste it into mathematica :D Is that not ok?

Comment: @belisarius I wasn't sure how to write some of the stuff in latex. I'll look it up and re-type it though.

Comment: Please, Oh Please! Until you master Mathematica: 1) don't use subscripts/superscripts and 2) Don't use Greek letters for posting here

Comment: Start reading [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/193) and then all the answers to that question

Comment: @belisarius Thanks, will do!

Comment: BTW, I see you've been around for about one year, but you don't vote too much and you usually don't accept answers to your questions. So, let me remind you: 1) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 2) Please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! (On your past questions TOO!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18278/discussion-between-logan-and-belisarius).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a numeric result you would need to assign numeric values to m, w, and h

```
int = Assuming[{Element[{m, w , h}, Reals], m w h > 0},
  Integrate[Exp[-p^2/(m w h)],
    {p, -Infinity, Sqrt[h m w]}] //
   Simplify]
```

> 1/2 Sqrt[[Pi]] Sqrt[h m w] (1 + Erf[1])

For example,

```
int /. {m -> 1., w -> 2. , h -> 2.}
```

> 3.2661

Comment: Thanks, that would make since. I was thinking the variables m and w would cancel out in the process because they are arbitrary in the problem I am working on but I figured it out. Thanks